# ZK proof that I possess a ZK proof for membership in $L$?

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, complexity-classes

A [zero-knowledge proof system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof) for a language $L$ is an [interactive
proof system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_proof_system) where a prover $P$ (a Turing machine) tries to convince a
verifier $V$ (a polynomially bounded Turing machine) in a sequence of
message exchanges that $x \in L$ so that $V$ learns nothing from the
interaction except whether $x \in L$ or not.

**Question.** Is it known how iterate this, i.e.: how to produce a ZK proof that I
possess a ZK proof for membership in $L$?

Comment: What would it mean to "possess" such a proof? ​ (possessing _the transcript_ of such a proof?) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I'm not sure how to define this properly. It's part of the question. A ZK proof system consists of a couple of TMs with certain properties. Can I demonstrate the possession of said TMs without leaking any other information?

Comment: Do you want it to be for the proof _system_ or just for a particular x? ​

Comment: @RickyDemer For the proof system. But I assume that the two problems are related.

Comment: In that case, something like [MIP*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0550v2.pdf) would be needed, since the property of L having a zero-knowledge proof system is undecidable by reduction from the halting problem. ​

Comment: @RickyDemer And for a given $x$?

Comment: For a given x and a [HVSZK](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:H#hvszk) proof system, "verifier accepts" is a proof of possession of a ZK proof, since the outer system's knowledge extractor gives the same output as the inner system's simulator. ​ For a given x and ZK proof systems that are _not_ HVSZK, things will be more complicated. ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. There is a ZK proof for every language in NP.  Roughly speaking, this means that if there's a way for someone to prove it (by giving a polynomial-size witness/proof), there's a way to prove it with a zero knowledge proof.

For instance, if you have a transcript of a ZK interaction, there's a polynomial-time algorithm to verify whether the ZK interaction should be accepted by the verifier, so it's possible to prove in ZK (i.e., it's possible to give a ZK proof) that you know a transcript of a ZK interaction that would be accepted by the verifier.  However, this might not be quite what you want, because this doesn't prove that the randomness was chosen randomly by the verifier.

Here's a better instance of what you're looking for.  Look up [non-interactive zero knowledge proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-interactive_zero-knowledge_proof).  Suppose I know a string $p$ that is a valid non-interactive zero knowledge (NIZK) proof of some statement $s$.  Moreover, there is a polynomial-time algorithm that allows verifying whether $p$ is a valid NIZK proof of $s$.  Therefore, there's a way I can use a ZK proof to prove to Alice in zero-knowledge that I know a string $p$ that is a valid NIZK proof of $s$, without revealing $p$ to Alice (because this is proving a NP statement).

That said, this probably isn't useful.  What would be the point?  I don't think this lets Alice conclude anything more than if I just proved in ZK to her that $s$ is true.